# array ng-options loop array can not find value

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

I send generate a list in C# controller and translate it to Json and angular receive that at front end. when i try to use ng-options to loop this array and get array value, i always got index.

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true" ng-model="groupArray" ng-options="k for (k,v) in groupArray">
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTf6x.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi a simple working example should be like this:

**Inside the controller**

$scope.JSONdata = [{
                'name' : 'Name 1',
                'sname' : 'Sname 1'
            },
            {
                'name': 'Name 2',
                'sname': 'Sname 2'
            },
            {
                'name': 'Name 3',
                'sname': 'Sname 3'
            }]

**From the front end**

```
<select ng-model='selectedName'
                ng-options='item as item.name for item in JSONdata'>            
</select>

//Retrieves the whole object. From here you can access both name and 
//sname of the selected item.
SelectedObject : {{selectedName}}
```

How the ng-options is working is like this :

1. Retrieve the whole item
2. Display only item.name in the options
   (select)
3. Whilst looping through every item in the JSONdata scope
   variable

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried  this in your `ng-options`?

`v for (k,v) in groupArray`

(I can't try at the moment and I am not sure, but it could be worth a try)

Comment: I tried, but i show me array size is 6, because it repeat twice. I donot know what happened.

Answer (score 0):

As per your object structure you can simply use.

```
v for (k,v) in groupArray
```

k is key and will return index, if you want to access the property value of any given object you can try something like.

```
v.propertyname for (k,v) in object
```

where `propertyname` is a property in your `object` structure.

For more information refer `ngOptions` docs [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)